# Bigquery query run generates a temp table that it is not used again

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

I have a question regarding how BigQuery works under the hood. I read in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#limitations) that BigQuery uses cached results when it tries to run the exact same query twice in a cached temp table that has generated in the first time that it run.

> When you run a duplicate query, BigQuery attempts to reuse cached results. To retrieve data from the cache, the duplicate query text must be the same as the original query.

But when I attempt to run the same query 2 times in a row the processing time is not faster. When I try to use the temp table that it is generated the response is instant.

**Example:**

- Run of the same original query twice:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

First time duration: 56 sec

Second time duration: 1 min 25 sec

- Run the query from the same temp generated table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `project._e552111cf62868acff9032079d48966c879f.b011854_b431_4889_92500bb0569489d`
```

Duration: 0 sec

Why BigQuery is not reusing the caching results from the temp table? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried querying a public dataset but the 2nd attempt is always instantaneous, But the bytes processed is tagged with cached results, Can you verify on your query about this, You can verify if your query is using cache by looking at the Job information. You can check the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#verifying_use_of_the_cache

Screenshot of output:

[image]